# Scan code for certain types

Tags: .net, c#-2.0

For a translation engine I need to return all objects of a certain type (labels, forms, user control, ...) used in our application. I tried to use reflection but the problem is that I also  instantiate some translatable object dynamically and I'm not sure if I can get thos with reflection.

Maybe reflection is not the right way to tackle this?

Any suggestions are welcom.

Thanks

Comment: How can you get a list of objects in memory? Do you have a "radix" from where you start?

Comment: I have a base usercontrol that itself contains a collection of ui elements. Its the base usercontrol that needs a function that needs to returns the list of translatable objects (set of ui controls).

Comment: @Tarscher: I have deleted my answer because is valid only for instantiated controls. If you need to read controls from the assemblies, the unique solution that comes to my mind is using reflection, but I'm sure that someone has a better idea.

Comment: Do you want all instances of a current type that are in operating memory?

Comment: not necessary in operating memory. I want to scan the code (not instantiated) for certain types that and return those.

Comment: So you don't want objects, you want types.

Comment: Winforms already has excellent support for localization with the Localizable property and satellite assemblies.  Avoid inventing your own scheme.

Comment: The translation system is external which I cant do anything about :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something similar to this complete example:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Assembly myassembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var baseType = typeof(ClassA);
        var theTypesIWant = myassembly.GetTypes().Where(t=> baseType.IsAssignableFrom(t));
    }
}

public class ClassB : ClassA
{ }
```

Granted, you can get a reference to the assembly in various ways.  Maybe this might be better:

```
var myAssembly2 = baseType.Assembly;
```

Let me know if this is insufficient.

**Edit**

You're using C# 2, so Linq isn't available.  Here's a modified form:

```
List<Type> theTypesIWant2 = new List<Type>();
foreach (var t in myAssembly2.GetTypes())
{
    if (baseType.IsAssignableFrom(t))
        theTypesIWant2.Add(t);
}
```